# Getting request url, posted data and other info from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java

How to get following values from HttpServeletRequest

```
-- requested url
-- previous requested url
-- type of request (GET or POST)
-- query params in case of GET request
-- posted data in case of POST request
```

I have to log above info from comming request.

Comment: see [HttpServletRequest api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 1):

As usual, you can find help in the documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

More specifically, check the following methods :

getMethod(), getRequestURL()

Looking into the documentation is not hard and always useful !

Comment: `getMethod()` is what returns you the "type" of request:
It "returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT."